# JavaScript - New object array from matched ID's

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I was just wondering the best way to approach this in JavaScript using ES6.

Using the following data:

```
categories: [
    {id: 1,name: "category 1",items: [19993, 99737]},
    {id: 2,name: "category 2",items: [70264, 65474, 07078]},
    {id: 3,name: "category 3",items: [76765]}
]

items: [
    {id: 19993, name: "item 1"},
    {id: 70264, name: "item 2"},
    {id: 99737, name: "item 3"},
    {id: 65474, name: "item 4"},
    {id: 76765, name: "item 5"},
    {id: 07078, name: "item 6"}
]
```

I'm trying to create a new array of items for each category, based on the ID's included in the categories.items array.

So for category 1 the output should be:

```
[
    {id: 19993, name: "item 1"},
    {id: 99737, name: "item 3"}
]
```

I know I can do this with a mess of loops, pushing into an array but was wondering if there was an shorter ES6 way of achieving this?

Thanks

Comment: You're asking for the _"best way"_ which will generate primarily opinion-based answers (which is why there are already three different answers...) - which is off-topic for SO

Comment: By the way, "shorter" is not "better". Looking for the shortest possible code is a naive approach of programming. Think of performances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could find the category and the items.

```js
function getItemsByCategory(id) {
    var category = categories.find(o => o.id === id);
    if (category) {
        return category.items.map(id => items.find(o => o.id === id));
    }
}

var categories = [{ id: 1, name: "category 1", items: [19993, 99737] }, { id: 2, name: "category 2", items: [70264, 65474, 07078] }, { id: 3, name: "category 3", items: [76765] }],
    items = [{ id: 19993, name: "item 1" }, { id: 70264, name: "item 2" }, { id: 99737, name: "item 3" }, { id: 65474, name: "item 4" }, { id: 76765, name: "item 5" }, { id: 07078, name: "item 6" }];

console.log(getItemsByCategory(1));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) by item `id` out of the `items` array. Use [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to iterate the `categories` array. For each category, create a new object using [object spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax), and populate the items array from the Map:

```js
const categories = [{"id":1,"name":"category 1","items":[19993,99737]},{"id":2,"name":"category 2","items":[70264,65474,7078]},{"id":3,"name":"category 3","items":[76765]}]

const items = [{"id":19993,"name":"item 1"},{"id":70264,"name":"item 2"},{"id":99737,"name":"item 3"},{"id":65474,"name":"item 4"},{"id":76765,"name":"item 5"},{"id":7078,"name":"item 6"}]

const itemsMap = new Map(items.map(o => [o.id, o]))

const result = categories.map(o => ({
  ...o,
  items: o.items.map(id => itemsMap.get(id))
}))

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it succinctly using [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), [`Array.prototype.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) and [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```js
const categories = [
    {id: 1,name: "category 1",items: [19993, 99737]},
    {id: 2,name: "category 2",items: [70264, 65474, 07078]},
    {id: 3,name: "category 3",items: [76765]}
];

const items = [
    {id: 19993, name: "item 1"},
    {id: 70264, name: "item 2"},
    {id: 99737, name: "item 3"},
    {id: 65474, name: "item 4"},
    {id: 76765, name: "item 5"},
    {id: 07078, name: "item 6"}
];

const result = categories.map(c => ({
    ...c,
    items: c.items.map(id => items.find(i => id === i.id)).filter(Boolean)
}));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: @leaf, awesome! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**reduce**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), [**forEach**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and [**find**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

Here idea is

- First for each item array in categories we find the matching element in `items` variable.
- If we find a matching element we add it to op else return op without any change

```js
let categories = [{id: 1,name: "category 1",items: [19993, 99737]},{id: 2,name: "category 2",items: [70264, 65474, 07078]},{id: 3,name: "category 3",items: [76765]}]
let items = [{id: 19993, name: "item 1"},{id: 70264, name: "item 2"},{id: 99737, name: "item 3"},   {id: 65474, name: "item 4"},{id: 76765, name: "item 5"},{id: 07078, name: "item 6"},]

let op = categories.reduce((op, {name, items:cartItems}) => {
  cartItems.forEach(key => {
    let value = items.find(({id}) => id === key)
    if(value){
      op[name] = op[name] || []
      op[name].push(value)
    }
  })
  return op
},{})

console.log(op)
```